# Beware the dangling -Xfrontend: (was Xcode: Archive fails, but builds and runs for simulator and devices)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Trying to Archive my app is failing with the following error(s):

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'CoreFoundation'
```

The project builds and runs on both the simulator and my iPhone, and builds for "Generic iOS Device".

The one big thing that I've changed in my project is how I'm integrating GooglePlaces and GoogleMaps. Previously, I had been using a hacked Carthage integration method, but that started failing to build when Archiving, though again worked fine in all other scenarios.

So I removed the Carthage integration and followed the Google prescribed way of manually integrating it, which involved adding a variety of frameworks to the `Link Binary With Libraries` Build Phase. CoreFoundation was not one of them, but including that didn't fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Well after painstakingly going through commits to determine exactly where it broke I figured out the problem.

> TL;DR - if you have a compiler option that is `-Xfrontend` without another
> option following, it is a mistake and will break things!

While cleaning up all warnings, I changed what I thought was an option to warn about functions taking more than x to compile:

```makefile
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=150";
```

In Xcode, this appears to be 2 options on 2 lines, so I deleted the second one. I was not thinking about `-Xfrontend` so I left it in. For debug builds I left in the whole thing but upped the number.

`-Xfrontend` is a 2 part option which passes along the option that follows to the front end compiler. So what was happening is that *whatever* followed was not only passed to the Swift front end compiler, but not passed to where it should be.

Comment: Where does this get added to?

Comment: Go to `Build Settings ➔ Swift Compiler - Custom Flags ➔ Other Swift Flags`